# How to call a method in xaml.cs file from BaseViewModel xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement of opening `alert dialog` when a event is firing in `Baseviewmodel`. `alert dialog` opening logic is written in `xaml.cs` file's `button` click handler.

```
//BaseViewModel event
 void CloseDialog()
 {
    //Call xaml.cs file `OpenDiaglog` event here
 }
```

This is `xaml.cs` file's method which I need to call

```
void OpenDiaglog()
  {
    lblZoomedView.IsVisible = true;
    zoomViewFrame.IsVisible = true;
    innerpersonnelGrid.IsVisible = false;
    btnNextZoomedView.IsVisible = true;
    btnNext.IsVisible = false;
  }
```

What I need to use `MessagingCenter` or `Subscsribers`, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using `MessegingCenter`.

In `BaseViewModel`

```
//BaseViewModel event   
void CloseDialog()
 {     
    //Call xaml.cs file `OpenDiaglog` event here
    MessagingCenter.Send(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Hi");
 }
```

In `xaml.cs` file

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
 {
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Xamarin.Forms.Application>(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Hi", (sender) =>
     {
        OpenDiaglog();
     });
 }
```